# brew install bind fails with "configure: error: OpenSSL was not found..."

Tags: macos, openssl, bind, homebrew

On a virgin OS X Mavricks (10.9.3) install, when I run the following command I get the following error.

Command:

```
brew install bind
```

Error:

```
==> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/homebrew/Cellar/bind/9.10.0-P2 --enable-threads --

enable-ipv6 --with-ssl-dir=/usr/local/opt/openssl
checking for sysconf... yes
checking for libtool... no
checking for Source Identity Token support... no
checking for OpenSSL library... configure: error: OpenSSL was not found in any of /usr /usr/local /usr/local/ssl /usr/pkg /usr/sfw; use --with-openssl=/path
If you don't want OpenSSL, use --without-openssl
```

Since OS X 10.9 already ships with openSSL, I've tried the following, but it gives the same message:

```
brew install bind --with-ssl=/usr/local/opt/openssl
```

What's the best way to fix?

Answer (score 7):

Sorry, easy answer, this fixed it:

```
ln -s /usr/local/opt/openssl /usr/local/ssl
```